# How to crop video to a particular size?

Tags: ios, swift, video

I have followed this link for cropping and resizing video:

[Swift: Crop and Export Video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660975/swift-crop-and-export-video#)

I want to crop and resize video to 612*612.
My code is given below:

```
 let outputPath : NSString = NSString(format: "%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), "output.mov")

    let outputURL : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: outputPath as String)!

    let fileManager : NSFileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    if(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(outputPath as String))
    {
        let asset : AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: outputURL, options: nil)
        if let clipVideoTrack: AVAssetTrack = asset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0] as? AVAssetTrack
        {

            var videoComposition: AVMutableVideoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
            videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 60)

            print(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height)

            videoComposition.renderSize = CGSizeMake(612,612)

            var instruction: AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
            instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(60, 30))
            var transformer: AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction =
            AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(assetTrack: clipVideoTrack)

            var t1: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, 0)

            var t2: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, CGFloat(M_PI_2))

            var finalTransform: CGAffineTransform = t2

             transformer.setTransform(finalTransform, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
            instruction.layerInstructions = NSArray(object: transformer) as [AnyObject]

            videoComposition.instructions = NSArray(object: instruction) as [AnyObject]


            let exportPath : NSString = NSString(format: "%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), "output2.mov")

            var exportUrl: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(exportPath as! String)!
            if(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(exportPath as String))
            {
                var error:NSError? = nil
                if(fileManager.removeItemAtPath(exportPath as String, error: &error))
                {
                    //Error - handle if requried
                }
            }

            var exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
            exporter.videoComposition = videoComposition
            exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
            exporter.outputURL = exportUrl
            exporter.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({ () -> Void in

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    () -> Void in
                    let outputURL:NSURL = exporter.outputURL;
                    self.videoURL = outputURL
                    let asset:AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: outputURL, options: nil)

                }

            })

        }


    }
```

I get size video size as 612*612 but content is weird. What could be the issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you rotate the Video-Clip in:    <code>var t2: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, CGFloat(M_PI_2))</code>

Comment: @MarcusAlexanderInzinger I have followed the solution which is given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660975/swift-crop-and-export-video#

Comment: Ok ... what happens if you try this:  var t2: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, 0) ?

Comment: @MarcusAlexanderInzinger its shifting right side which is currently on left side. But still wrong size with black background

Comment: Can you post a sceenshot?

Comment: @MarcusAlexanderInzinger in code made changes are:
 `var t1: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height, -(clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.width - clipVideoTrack.naturalSize.height)/2)
                var t2: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(t1, 0)
                var finalTransform: CGAffineTransform = t2`

Comment: Whats your original Video-Size?

Comment: @MarcusAlexanderInzinger original video size is : 360 * 480

Comment: @MarcusAlexanderInzinger did u get any solution? please help, I am stuck in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got solution:
I have set value of AVCaptureSession to AVCaptureSessionPresetiFrame960x540
and I changed its value to AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720 solve my issue.