# Crop *Video* to Square using UIImagePickerController w/ Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

I'm currently using UIImagePickerController to record video and upload videos from the local album store.

I would like to crop all videos to square after selecting/recording. Is there a way to do this without using AVFoundation?

If AVFoundation is the only way, how do I approach it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Crop and Export Video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660975/swift-crop-and-export-video)